# What are possible filters in Joomla form fields?

Tags: jform, form-fields-types, fields

I see intermittent use of `filter="safehtml"` and `filter="string"` throught Joomla forms.  Is there a complete list, and can custom filters be created?

Comment: FYI:
The JForm filters are now in /libraries/src/Form/Form.php method filterField

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The possible filters are:

- **rules** (Access Control Rules)
- **unset** (Do nothing, thus leaving the return value as null)
- **raw** (No filter)
- **int_array** (Filter the input as an array of integers)
- **safehtml** (Filter safe HTML)
- **server_utc** (Convert a date to UTC based on the server timezone offset)
- **user_utc** (Convert a date to UTC based on the user timezone offset)
- **url** (URL filter which also ensure the protocol is present)
- **tel** (Filter for phone number. It will try and match against specific patterns, else return a string of numbers)

For a full list of jInput filters and how to use them, see [Retrieving request data using JInput](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput).

Hope this helps

Comment: Where did you get/find this?  Am looking at `joomla\libraries\filter\input.php`, and see some from your list and others that you haven't included.

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/form/form.php#L1230

Comment: @GDP - The filters in the file you mentioned are for JInput as show [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)

Comment: Ah, there it is....always have a hell of a time finding it, so thought it was a worthwhile question.

Comment: No worries. As for the custom filters, you can most likely create your own by extending the class, but have never tried this.

Comment: In joomla 3.9.24 unit tests suite on the official joomla-cms repo you can find some more filter type such as php custom function,  php custom method, word, and int  here is the link https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3.9.24/tests/unit/suites/libraries/joomla/form/JFormDataHelper.php#L50:L101